# "Ищи меня" - why not "ищи мне"?

Tags: грамматика, перевод, падежи

The translator say "ищи меня" means "search for me".

At first I thought, okay, this seems correct because ищи is the imperative of искать.

However, my dictionary say that you use искать with dative - but меня is not dative??

So why is it меня and not мне?

Comment: Welcome to the Russian SE! Can you please update your question with information about what exact dictionary you are using?  Искать can be combined not only with Dative and every descent dictionary should indicate that. 

"Ищи мне" is "search for me" (as in do this job for someone else), "ищи меня" is "search me" OR "search for me" - as in looking for someone.

Comment: @shabunc: Correct. "Ищи мне" means "search [this item] for me". "ищи меня" means "I am hidden. Search for me". Actually this is English language what causes two different meanings to collapse into the same letters.

Comment: This is one of the most difficult parts of learning Russian for most people. You can't just look something up in a dictionary and take what you find. You have to understand what a possible translation means and decide whether it is what you want to say. Because English has lost most of its cases the expression "Find me" is unclear without context. In the sentences "You can't find me." and "Find me a pencil." it means very different things. You need to look at the cases of "Ищи меня" and "Ищи мне" and figure out what each means. Cases are not decorative. Mix them up and you say something silly.